# How to disable Autowiring in Spring JUnit Tests?

Tags: spring, unit-testing, testing, junit4

Im currently working on a tool, which analyzes ApplicationContexts of Spring applications. To start the analysis I had implemented an abstract JUnit-Test class, which has to be extended by an concrete instance in the target application. This makes it very easy to write own Tests for further context-files and my tool could use the context loading functionality as well.

The problem for me is that Spring-based JUnit-Tests automatically enable Autowiring, even when it is not enabled in the target context. But I need the unchanged context, to ensure the correctness of the analysis results.

My abstract Test-Class which is embedded in the analysis tool looks like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public abstract class AbstractContextLoader implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Test
    public void analyseContext() {
        SpringContextAnalysis.startApplication(applicationContext);
    }

    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }
}
```

A concrete implementation could look like this:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations="context.xml")
public class ContextAnalysis extends AbstractContextLoader {
}
```

**Is it possible to disable the automatic instantiation of Autowiring-Components while using Spring-based JUnit-Tests?**

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try storing it in an Object and casting it when needed? You'll need to do the same with the setter method's parameter.

Otherwise you could try annotating it with `@Autowired(required=false)`, but I doubt that would work.